# Can PE file sections be moved in memory relative to base address when the image is loaded?

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable, delay-load

I'm trying to access a delayed loaded function address in the `Import Address Table` for an arbitrary process.

My assumptions went like this:

First, I need to see where it is located in the image itself relative to the base address:

```
DWORD_PTR dwFuncOffset = get_IAT_entry_offset_for_imported_function(
    L"path-to\\TargetProc.exe", "WTSAPI32.dll", "WTSOpenServerW");
wprintf(L"Offset is 0x%p\n", dwFuncOffset);
```

Here's some abbreviated version of the lookup in the PE header. I removed most error checks to make it readable:

```
#include <delayimp.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")


PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER getEnclosingSectionHeader(DWORD_PTR rva, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeader)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pNTHeader);

    for (WORD i = 0 ; i < pNTHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++, section++)
    {
        // Is the RVA within this section?
        if((rva >= section->VirtualAddress) && 
                (rva < (section->VirtualAddress + section->Misc.VirtualSize)))
        {
            return section;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

LPVOID GetPtrFromRVA(DWORD_PTR rva, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeader, DWORD_PTR imageBase)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSectionHdr = getEnclosingSectionHeader(rva, pNTHeader);
    if (!pSectionHdr)
        return 0;

    INT_PTR delta = (INT_PTR)(pSectionHdr->VirtualAddress - pSectionHdr->PointerToRawData);
    return (PVOID)(imageBase + rva - delta);
}


DWORD_PTR get_IAT_entry_offset_for_imported_function(LPCTSTR pImageFilePath, LPCSTR pImportDllName, LPCSTR pImportFuncName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE hOpenFileMapping = NULL;
    const BYTE* lpBaseAddress = NULL;

    __try
    {
        hFile = CreateFile(pImageFilePath, 
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        hOpenFileMapping = ::CreateFileMapping(hFile,
                NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);

        lpBaseAddress = (const BYTE*)::MapViewOfFile(hOpenFileMapping,
                FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

        if(!lpBaseAddress)
            return 0;

        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeader = ::ImageNtHeader((PVOID)lpBaseAddress);

        _ASSERT(pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.Magic == IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC);  //32-bit only here

        IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32* pIOH32 = &reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32>(pNtHeader)->OptionalHeader;
        PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY pDataDirectories = pDataDirectories = pIOH32->DataDirectory;

        IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY* pDLoadTbl = &pDataDirectories[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT];

        ImgDelayDescr *pImportDescriptor = (ImgDelayDescr*)GetPtrFromRVA(
            pDLoadTbl->VirtualAddress, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

        //Go through all DLLs
        for(; pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT; pImportDescriptor++)
        {
            //Get DLL name
            LPCSTR pStrDllName = (LPCSTR)GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaDLLName,
                pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

            //Look for specific import dll
            if(lstrcmpiA(pStrDllName, pImportDllName) != 0)
                continue;

            IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 *pITD_IAT = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32*)
                GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

            IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32 *pITD_INT = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32*)
                GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaINT, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

            //Go through all imported functions from this DLL
            for(; pITD_INT->u1.AddressOfData != 0; pITD_IAT++, pITD_INT++)
            {
                if(IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL32(pITD_INT->u1.Ordinal))
                    continue;

                IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME* pIIBY = (IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME*)
                    GetPtrFromRVA(pITD_INT->u1.AddressOfData, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);
                if(!pIIBY)
                    continue;

                //Pick only specific imported function
                if(lstrcmpiA((LPCSTR)pIIBY->Name, pImportFuncName) != 0)
                    continue;

                //Get this function's offset in IAT relative to base address
                return (DWORD_PTR)pITD_IAT - (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress;
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        ::UnmapViewOfFile(lpBaseAddress);
        ::CloseHandle(hOpenFileMapping);
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return 0;   //failed
}
```

Then I build the `TargetProc.exe` as a simple console project with `WTSAPI32.dll` set for delayed loading:

[image]

`TargetProc.exe` has only this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#include <Wtsapi32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wtsapi32.lib")


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Get base address for this image
    void* pBaseAddr = (void*)::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    ::WTSOpenServerW(NULL);     //Set up for delayed loading

    return 0;
}
```

I then run my first project that gives me that `WTSOpenServerW` function's IAT entry offset from the base of `TargetProc.exe` is:

```
Offset is 0x00007670
```

which I can verify with a debugger:

[image]

---

Then the second stage is to check it.

So if I run my `TargetProc.exe` in Visual Studio, I can first get its base address (which happened to be `0x890000`):

[image]

Then I can step into the `WTSOpenServerW` function to see the location of its IAT entry:

[image]

Skip that jump, it's added here only in the debugger build.

And this is where it actually reads the address of the `WTSOpenServerW` function from its IAT entry for the `jmp` instruction:

[image]

I get its IAT entry at address `0x008AB070`, which happens to be at `0x1B070` byte offset from the base address (i.e. `0x008AB070` - `0x890000` = `0x1B070`), instead of my expected `0x7670` that I calculated above.

So what am I doing wrong in my calculations?

PS. PE header structure [reference 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [reference 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#delay_import_address_table).

Comment: `return (DWORD_PTR)pITD_IAT - (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress;` is error - here really returned file offset but not rva

Comment: simply use `ULONG rvaIAT = pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT` as is (not convert it to file offset via `GetPtrFromRVA` ) and increment it in loop `rvaIAT += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32)` and return as is - this will be rva

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. But why can't I use just an offset from the beginning of the file? What's the purpose of that `rva`?

Comment: but are you understand different between rva and file offset ? you return file offset from function - `0x7670` is file offset. when `0x1b070` is rva

Comment: @RbMm: I guess I don't understand the `rva` part.

Comment: but how you use say `GetPtrFromRVA` (which convert rva to file offset) if you not understand what is rva ?!

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, I understand that it loops through sections and gets the one that intersects with the pointer. If this is the case, it means that sections can be moved around in the PE file when it's loaded for execution. Is that correct?

Comment: of course sections is moved - look again to `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` structure and try understand it. The RVA of an item almost always differs from its position within the file on disk (file pointer).

Comment: @RbMm: OK, then. That was my mistake. Appreciate it! So just to make sure I understand it completely: the PE file sections can be moved around in memory when image is loaded, but nothing within those sections can. Am I correct now?

Comment: yes, every section is moved from `PointerToRawData` (it file offset) to `VirtualAddress` (it rva or offset in memory). so how move section - described in it header. *but nothing within those sections can* - yes, data in section already not moved

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. One side question though. Can I traverse through the PE file structure (similar to my `get_IAT_entry_offset_for_imported_function` method) in a running process by reading its VM or via DLL injection?

Comment: very strange question. of course yes. and traverse file mapped as image - more easy - you not need all time convert rva to file offset

Comment: @RbMm: The reason I'm asking is that I have some trouble doing it. If I use my `get_IAT_entry_offset_for_imported_function()` method inside `TargetProc.exe` process and set `lpBaseAddress = (const BYTE*)::GetModuleHandle(NULL)`, in other words, run it on self virtual memory, it doesn't work anymore. The first time `pImportDescriptor` is all 0's as if the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT` directory is empty.

Comment: i huge count of times parse pe structures, delay-load as well. this is perfect worked for "self virtual memory"

Comment: your `get_IAT_entry_offset_for_imported_function` designed for work with plain mapped module. when module mapped as image - (use `SEC_IMAGE` in call `CreateFileMapping`) need another code - instead `GetPtrFromRVA` need simply `(PBYTE)ImageBase + rva`

Comment: @RbMm: I think I got it working. Had to post code in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working. I'm not sure if there's a better way to optimize `GetPtrFromRVA` function calls though, that could eat up some CPU clocks for a larger PE file.

So the short answer to my original question is yes, PE file sections can be relocated in memory in relation to their position in the PE file when the file is mapped for execution.

And here are two ways to read the Import Address Table (in my case for delayed loaded DLLs): from an image file and from the current process memory. (There's also a third way of getting it from another running process by reading its virtual memory. [This guy shows how](https://github.com/m0n0ph1/IAT-Hooking-Revisited). In that case my approach though would be to inject my DLL into a process and use `parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromMem()` method.)

```
wprintf(L"Memory:----------------------\n");
parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromMem((void*)::GetModuleHandle(NULL), TRUE);

wprintf(L"File:----------------------\n");
WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileName(NULL, buff, _countof(buff));
parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromFile(buff);
```

And then the code itself:
(Note that there's also an old style PE header format, used by Visual Studio 6.0, which I had to account for as well.)

```
BOOL parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromFile(LPCTSTR pImageFilePath)
{
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE hOpenFileMapping = NULL;
    void* lpBaseAddress = NULL;

    __try
    {
        hFile = CreateFile(pImageFilePath, 
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        hOpenFileMapping = ::CreateFileMapping(hFile,
                NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);

        lpBaseAddress = (void*)::MapViewOfFile(hOpenFileMapping,
                FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

        if(!lpBaseAddress)
            return FALSE;

        return parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromMem(lpBaseAddress, FALSE);
    }
    __finally
    {
        ::UnmapViewOfFile(lpBaseAddress);
        ::CloseHandle(hOpenFileMapping);
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return FALSE;
}


BOOL parsePEheader_DelayLoad_FromMem(void* lpBaseAddress, BOOL bImage)
{
    __try
    {
        PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pDummy;
        ULONG uiDummy;
        ImgDelayDescr *pImportDescriptor = (ImgDelayDescr*)ImageDirectoryEntryToDataEx(
            lpBaseAddress, bImage, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT, &uiDummy, &pDummy);

        if(pImportDescriptor)
        {
            const char* base = (char*)lpBaseAddress;

            IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pNtHeader = 
                (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((BYTE*)lpBaseAddress + 
                ((IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)lpBaseAddress)->e_lfanew);

            DWORD_PTR uiPreferredBase = pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;

            //Go thru all DLLs
            while(pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT)
            {
                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA nameTable = 0;
                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA funcTable = 0;

                const char* dllName;
                BOOL bOldStyle;

                if(pImportDescriptor->grAttrs & 1)
                {
                    bOldStyle = FALSE;

                    if(!bImage)
                    {
                        nameTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
                            GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaINT, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

                        funcTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
                            GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

                        dllName = (const char*)
                            GetPtrFromRVA(pImportDescriptor->rvaDLLName, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nameTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(base + pImportDescriptor->rvaINT);
                        funcTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(base + pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT);

                        dllName = base + pImportDescriptor->rvaDLLName;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Old style PE file, compiled with VC++ 6.0
                    //Cannot be 64-bit
                    _ASSERT(sizeof(DWORD_PTR) == sizeof(DWORD));
                    bOldStyle = TRUE;

                    if(!bImage)
                    {
                        nameTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
                            GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD_PTR)pImportDescriptor->rvaINT - uiPreferredBase, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

                        funcTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
                            GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD_PTR)pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT - uiPreferredBase, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);

                        dllName = (LPCSTR)((DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress + (DWORD_PTR)pImportDescriptor->rvaDLLName - uiPreferredBase);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nameTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(base + pImportDescriptor->rvaINT - uiPreferredBase);
                        funcTable = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(base + pImportDescriptor->rvaIAT - uiPreferredBase);

                        dllName = base + pImportDescriptor->rvaDLLName - uiPreferredBase;
                    }
                }


                printf("Delay Loaded DLL: %s\n", dllName);

                while(nameTable->u1.AddressOfData)
                {
                    // check whether this is imported by ordinal only
                    if(nameTable->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
                    {
                        WORD ordinal = static_cast<WORD>(nameTable->u1.Ordinal & (~IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG));

                        printf("ordinal: %u", ordinal);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME funcNameStruct;
                        if(!bImage)
                        {
                            if(!bOldStyle)
                            {
                                funcNameStruct = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)
                                    GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD_PTR)nameTable->u1.AddressOfData, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                funcNameStruct = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)
                                    GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD_PTR)nameTable->u1.AddressOfData - uiPreferredBase, pNtHeader, (DWORD_PTR)lpBaseAddress);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(!bOldStyle)
                            {
                                funcNameStruct = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)
                                    (base + (DWORD_PTR)nameTable->u1.AddressOfData);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                funcNameStruct = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)
                                    (base + (DWORD_PTR)nameTable->u1.AddressOfData - uiPreferredBase);
                            }
                        }

                        char* pFuncName = (char*)funcNameStruct->Name;

                        printf("func: %s", pFuncName);
                    }

                    printf("\tAddr: [0x%p]=0x%p\n", 
                        funcTable, *(DWORD_PTR*)funcTable);

                    nameTable++;
                    funcTable++;
                }

                pImportDescriptor++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"There's no Delay loaded DLLs\n");
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        wprintf(L"\nException! Bad address, not a PE file, or something goofed up...\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And lastly, in case you don't want to link to `Dbghelp.lib` just to use its couple functions, these are their C implementations:

```
PVOID WINAPI ImageDirectoryEntryToDataEx( PVOID base, BOOLEAN image, USHORT dir, PULONG size, PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *section )
{
    const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *nt;
    DWORD addr;

    *size = 0;
    if (section)
        *section = NULL;

    if (!(nt = RtlImageNtHeader( (HMODULE)base ))) 
        return NULL;

    if (dir >= nt->OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes) 
        return NULL;
    if (!(addr = nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dir].VirtualAddress)) 
        return NULL;

    *size = nt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dir].Size;
    if (image || addr < nt->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders) 
        return (char *)base + addr;

    return RtlImageRvaToVa( nt, (HMODULE)base, addr, section );
}

PVOID WINAPI RtlImageRvaToVa( const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *nt, HMODULE module, DWORD rva, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER **section )
{
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *sec;

    if (section && *section)
    {
        sec = *section;
        if ((sec->VirtualAddress <= rva) && (sec->VirtualAddress + sec->SizeOfRawData > rva))
            goto lbl_use_it;
    }

    if (!(sec = RtlImageRvaToSection( nt, module, rva ))) 
        return NULL;

lbl_use_it:

    if (section) 
        *section = sec;

    return (char *)module + sec->PointerToRawData + (rva - sec->VirtualAddress);
}

PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER WINAPI RtlImageRvaToSection( const IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *nt, HMODULE module, DWORD rva )
{
    int i;
    const IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *sec;

    sec = (const IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*)(
        (const char*)&nt->OptionalHeader + nt->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);

    for (i = 0; i < nt->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++, sec++)
    {
        if ((sec->VirtualAddress <= rva) && (sec->VirtualAddress + sec->SizeOfRawData > rva))
            return (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)sec;
    }

    return NULL;
}

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS WINAPI RtlImageNtHeader(HMODULE hModule)
{
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *ret;

    __try
    {
        IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dos = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)hModule;

        ret = NULL;
        if (dos->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        {
            ret = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((char *)dos + dos->e_lfanew);
            if (ret->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) 
                ret = NULL;
        }
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}
```